# Examples to some complicated JSON tree structures

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, data-structures

I am looking to compile a list of JSON feeds publicly available on Internet that are  complicated and have a lot of levels in it. I am looking at something like 3+ levels, and different data structures.

The purpose of this collection is to provide as example for students who learn traversing Arrays. (The JSON will be converted to associative array.)

Somehow the examples should be real life use, like:
- weather feeds
- dbpedia open feeds
- even facebook albums (although requires api key, but is easy to obtain).

There are sites that list JSON examples: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/10-example-json-files/ but I consider them too easy.

I am looking for at least 10 other examples.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right kind of question for this site.

Comment: @Ariel please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq This question reflects: practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't name 10 but here's some links to resources that I've used that might be a good starting point.

The BBC have a great deal of publicly available resources, some details of which can be found [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/developers) and [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/developers/api/). For example:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/programmes/genres.json

http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/programmes/genres/drama/scifiandfantasy/schedules/upcoming.json

Musicbrainz also have a rich structure JSON API - http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Development/JSON_Web_Service

There is also the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) and [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) but they might not have as many levels as you want.

If you have a Twitter account, some parts of the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) are 3+ nested levels.